# Use slickgrid inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slickgrid

Is it possible to user slickgrid inside a bootstrap modal?

I tried and the slick-viewport div height is set to 2px instead of the right size. I'm also using expand and collapse buttons, but when I expand, only the current number of rows is shown, adding a scroll but with extra empty lines instead of the child lines of the expanded node.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried manually initing the grid AFTER the modal finishes loading? Using `explicitInitialization: true` as explained in http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-explicit-initialization.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try manually init-ing the grid **after** the modal finishes loading. You can do this using `explicitInitialization: true` as explained in http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-explicit-initialization.html

P.S. - adding this as an answer, so you could accept this if you wish.

---

Edit by KevinB:

To add, you can bind to the modal's `shown` event to perform the init with proper timing.

```
$("#modal").on("shown",function(){
    grid.init();
});
```