# Can I call a function after AngularUI collapse has finished rendering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, slickgrid

I'm using [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) inside a Bootstrap modal, I had some issues rendering it when the modal is opened, but I fixed it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652774/use-slickgrid-inside-a-bootstrap-modal) answer.

Now I'm using [AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) collapse directive to expand and collapse parts of the modal. In one part I modify the data in the slickgrid, and then in another I view the slickgrid. However when I expand the slickgrid part after modifying it, the slickgrid again renders incorrectly, with only one column showing.

I tried calling `grid.render()` or `grid.resizeCanvas()` after each modification, but it doesn't work.

So my question is, can I render the grid after the collapse/expand action has finished rendering?